# Swagger Error - description: "Not a valid parameter definition"

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I am trying to define a simple swagger definition for a rest api. I am getting error on all my parameter section.

I am getting following swagger definition error in the swagger editor, I am not getting any clue what i wrong. please advise.

**Swagger definition:**

```
paths:
'/customer/{customerId}/accountlist':
get:
  responses:
    '200':
      description: ''
  parameters:
    - name: customerId
      in: path
      allowMultiple: false
      required: true
      type: string
  x-auth-type: None
  x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
  produces:
    - application/json
  x-scope: InternalUse
  swagger: '2.0'
  info:
  title: Sample
  description: API for Sample
```

**Swagger Error:**

```
Swagger Error
Not a valid parameter definition
Jump to line 7
Details
Object
code:  "ONE_OF_MISSING"
params: Array [0]
message:  "Not a valid parameter definition"
path: Array [5]
0:  "paths"
1:  "/customer/{customerId}/accountlist"
2:  "get"
3:  "parameters"
4:  "0"
schemaId:  "http://swagger.io/v2/schema.json#"
inner: Array [2]
0: Object
code:  "ONE_OF_MISSING"
params: Array [0]
message:  "Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'"
path: Array [5]
0:  "paths"
1:  "/customer/{customerId}/accountlist"
2:  "get"
3:  "parameters"
4:  "0"
inner: Array [2]
0: Object
code:  "OBJECT_MISSING_REQUIRED_PROPERTY"
params: Array [1]
0:  "schema"
message:  "Missing required property: schema"
path: Array [0]
1: Object
code:  "ONE_OF_MISSING"
params: Array [0]
message:  "Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'"
path: Array [0]
inner: Array [4]
1: Object
code:  "OBJECT_MISSING_REQUIRED_PROPERTY"
params: Array [1]
0:  "$ref"
message:  "Missing required property: $ref"
path: Array [5]
0:  "paths"
1:  "/customer/{customerId}/accountlist"
2:  "get"
3:  "parameters"
4:  "0"
level: 900
type:  "Swagger Error"
description:  "Not a valid parameter definition"
lineNumber: 7
```

Comment: Please include the Swagger / OpenAPI definition in your question preferably in YAML format.

Comment: Added sample swagger definition as part of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your OpenAPI spec.  This version is valid:

```
swagger: '2.0'

info:
  title: Sample
  version: 1.0.0
  description: API for Sample

paths:
  '/customer/{customerId}/accountlist':
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
      parameters:
        - name: customerId
          in: path
          required: true
          type: string
      x-auth-type: None
      x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
      produces:
        - application/json
      x-scope: InternalUse
```

Some comments about your original version:

- The indenting was bad.  For example the `get:` line needs to be indented from     the preceding line.  But perhaps that was just a copy & paste issue.
- The `info` object requires a `version` property.
- The `customerId` parameter included an `allowMultiple` property.  I was seeing an error until I removed that.